# Extension method c#

Tags: c#

```
class Program
    {
        public static int i = 0;
        public static void Main()
        {
            (i++).Print();
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static void Print(this int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Program.i);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

> OUTPUT: 1 0

Why when we pass just `i` its not incremented, and with `Program.i` is incremented?

Comment: Here the ++ happens before the Print call. That means the first time you call it, i is already 1 when using Program.I

Comment: Use `++i` if you want that the value is incremented before the method is called with it as argument

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that this is nothing to do with being an extension method.

The code in Main() is identical to this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Extensions.Print(Program.i++);
}
```

This also prints 1 and 0.

The answer to why this happens is now clearer:

1. The current value of `i`, 0, is captured ready to pass it to `Print()`.
2. The value of `Program.i` is incremented, so now it has the value 1.
3. `Print()` is called with the unincremented value of `i`.
4. `Program.i` is printed, thus printing 1.
5. The parameter `i` is printed, thus printing 0.

In fact, the C# compiler will compile `Main()` as follows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int num = Program.i;
    Program.i = num + 1;
    num.Print();
}
```

Or (in IL):

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main () cil managed 
{
    .entrypoint
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldsfld int32 Demo.Program::i
    IL_0006: dup
    IL_0007: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0008: add
    IL_0009: stsfld int32 Demo.Program::i
    IL_000e: call void Demo.Extensions::Print(int32)
    IL_0013: nop
    IL_0014: ret
}
```

The reason the compiler does this is because of the definition of the post-increment operator.

`Extensions.Print(Program.i++)` by definition must be called with the value of `Program.i` as it was before it was incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your `i` increments after the `Print()` method call (*postfix increment operation*, see [++ Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator)), this is why your output is '0', you need to increment it before calling `Print()` (*prefix increment operation*):

```
(++i).Print();
```

with `Console.WriteLine(i);`.

You can check that, if you call it within a loop, for example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        (i++).Print();
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static void Print(this string i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

you will get output:

> Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

but if you increment `i` before `Print()` method call, the result will be:

> Output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

And your `Program.i` gets 1, cause its call happens within `Print()` method and in that point `Program`'s `i` will be incremented.

Comment: @RandRandom well, tried to explain in updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is 0 because it executes the method before incrementing program's variable.

This is how to have 1 as output ^^

```
class Program
{
    public static int i = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        i++;
        i.Print();
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static void Print(this int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Program.i);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: Added explanation ^^

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are using the post-fix increment which means the value is incremented after the print method is executed

```
class Program
{
    public static int i = 0;
    public static void Main()
    {
        (i++).Print();//  increment after print
        (++i).Print();// print after increment
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static void Print(this int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

out put

0

2